# use terraform how to add custom domain to Azure front door

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-front-door

I had created Auzre front door,but have many custom domains want add to the front door.
can i use terraform do it?
my means is not create a new front door, only add the domains to the exist front door.
thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Its not possible as of now as there is no `data source` support for the [`azurerm_frontdoor`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/frontdoor). You have to create a new frontdoor with dynamic endpoints and custom_https_configuration by using resource block for adding multiple domains.

[image]

**You can refer the below code for creating new frontdoor with terraform :**

> 1. [Getting Started with Azure Front Door and Terraform | Coding With
>    Taz](https://codingwithtaz.blog/2020/06/15/getting-started-with-azure-front-door-and-terraform/)
> 2. [terraform-azurerm-front-door/r-front-door.tf at master ·
>    claranet/terraform-azurerm-front-door (github.com)](https://github.com/claranet/terraform-azurerm-front-door/blob/master/r-front-door.tf)